# UITableView rows inconsistency error on reload data

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I am deleting objects in a subview, and when I go back up the navigation stack to the parent table view and reload data I get the error

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 4. The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (58) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (59), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

So the number of rows 58, is correct, but how do I work around this error since I don't actually delete the items or rows in this view, but rather delete data in a subview. I don't physically delete any rows before the reload.  This parent view doesn't actually know what the sub-views are doing and just gets a fresh data source with all changes in the reload method.  The database has the item deleted in a subview and the reloading in a parent controller's tableviews shows this new updated item count.  Do I have to calculate how many less rows there are since the last update and decrement that somehow and set some rows deleted property?

Can I ignore the consistency check when I call the table's reloadData method?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section==recentPhotosCellIndex) {  
       return [arrayOfPosts count] 
    }
    else
       return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as the data source?  Are you sure you are removing it from there as well?  Notice that is says 0 rows were deleted.  Check to see that you are removing it from the view as well as the data source.

Comment: It's an NSMutableArray and the item is removed from the datasource by a sub-view.  0 rows were deleted but the datasource has less items.  I don't remove any rows from the view before the reload.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't hard coded your section/rows have you?

Comment: nope, it gets the number of rows from the datasource, the datasource is updated.

Comment: And I assume your calling a Delegate method to inform the presenting view up the stack to reload its data model before a [self.tableView reloadData]?

Comment: yeah, the data looks fine, it's only the reloadData that is erroring with the new updated data since it has less rows in it.